# How to add app icon for iPad Pro in Xcode

Tags: ipad, xcode, icon

In Xcode 7.1 and 7.1.1 there is no slot for app icon for iPad Pro. I have no idea how to put in an app icon for iPad Pro.

How can it be done? Does the App Store make the scaled version of the iPad Air app icon onto iPad Pro?

Comment: This fits better in Stack Overflow

Comment: Have you tried the Xcode 7.2 beta ??

Answer (score 3):

You need **Xcode 7.2 beta 3 or later** to add iPad Pro app icons (167 × 167) to asset catalogs.

[rdar://22915712](https://openradar.appspot.com/22915712)